# Missing disk space after failed Bootcamp install

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, windows

Earlier today, while running Bootcamp attempting to install Windows 7 on my late-2012 iMac, I suddenly lost 160g of disk space after Bootcamp failed to create the partition for Windows. Disk Utility reports that the main Fusion Drive is still 1.1tb, but the only *visible* partition is `Macintosh HD`, spanning only 950gb instead of the entire disk (minus the hidden recovery partition). Disk Utility also duly notes that there are only 2 partitions, which I assume to be the main harddrive and the recovery partition:

[image]
[image]

`diskutil cs list` actually shows what happened to the storage (note the free space, which exactly matches what I specified in Bootcamp):

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 320B77F3-91C2-4221-B24C-D8B91C233D32
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1120333864960 B (1.1 TB)
    Free Space:   160000114688 B (160.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume CEADFEBA-F128-40BE-A075-EBFD3877CDD6
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 8CECCFC2-E046-499F-B762-B278E2398F75
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     999345012736 B (999.3 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family E52D5439-ED00-4A23-97A7-70BCF34CBF41
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 933B0D1B-9E56-4DB3-8853-013BE1C2C6E4
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          951826382848 B (951.8 GB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

Trying to run `diskutil cs resizeVolume 933B0D1B-9E56-4DB3-8853-013BE1C2C6E4 0g` to give Macintosh HD the remaining space did't work out either:

```
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is 933B0D1B-9E56-4DB3-8853-013BE1C2C6E4
Started CoreStorage operation
Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair
```

`diskutil verifyDisk disk0` ends with the following:

```
The volume 320B77F3-91C2-4221-B24C-D8B91C233D32 appears to be OK
Storage system check exit code is 0
Incorrect size for volume "Macintosh HD"
Problems were found with the partition map which might prevent booting
Error: -69688: Incorrect size for logical volume
```

`gpt -r show` gives the following:

```
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  236306352      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236715992     262144      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  236978136          7         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this Free Space back, preferably without needing to wipe my harddrive?

Answer (score 1):

You need to reinstall Mac OS X

Backup your system/data.

1. Boot into Internet Recovery (CMD + R + i)
2. Open Terminal
3. Erase your Macintosh HD Volume

   ```
   diskutil cs deleteVolume 933B0D1B-9E56-4DB3-8853-013BE1C2C6E4
   ```
4. Erase Macintosh Volume Group

   ```
   diskutil cs delete 320B77F3-91C2-4221-B24C-D8B91C233D32
   ```
5. Erase SSD this should disk0, verify!

   ```
   diskutil eraseDisk jhfs+ SSD disk0
   ```
6. Erase HDD this should disk1, verify!

   ```
   diskutil eraseDisk jhfs+ HDD disk1
   ```
7. Create LV Group (order is critical SSD and HDD in that order, verify!)

   ```
   diskutil cs create OSX-MacintoshLVG disk0s2 disk1s2
   ```
8. Create Logical Volume

   ```
   diskutil cs createVolume <UUID from Step 7> jhfs+ "Macintosh HD" 100%
   ```
9. Restore from TM or reinstall Mac OS

Comment: Thanks for Edit some problems reformat between Markdown and code.